# Git bash looks for node/npm modules in wrong place

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, git-bash

When I run any of the node modules installed globally from git bash it throws me an error that it can't find (just!) installed module , in this example I am trying to create a new project with sails.js :

```html
sails(master) > sails new test-project
module.js:538
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\Git\node_modules\sails\bin\sails.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
sails(master) >
```

Well, of course it can't find it, because all these packages are installed in Appdata/Roaming/npm/node_modules and happily reside there where they should.. **So how can I point out to git bash to look in right the place?** And what should be this exact right place? And it happens with every new package is it sails, or express..I couldn't figure out it myself and wasted a lot of time googling it. I know that the problem would seem ridiculous for experienced user, but I am quite newbie in node env. In my env.variables I have:
User variables: blabla\Appdata\Roaming\npm
System variables: ..C:\Users\Tomy\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs

```html
Desktop(master) > printenv | grep PATH= | tr ':' '\n'
MYSQLCONNECTOR_ASSEMBLIESPATH=C
\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector.NET 6.9\Assemblies\v4.5
EXEPATH=C
\Program Files\Git
GTK_BASEPATH=C
\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\
ACLOCAL_PATH=/mingw64/share/aclocal
/usr/share/aclocal
MANPATH=/mingw64/share/man
/usr/local/man
/usr/share/man
/usr/man
/share/man
PATH=/c/Users/Tomy/bin
/mingw64/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/mingw64/bin
/usr/bin
/c/Users/Tomy/bin
/c/Ruby24-x64/bin
/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath
/c/Program Files/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/Windows Live
/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/Windows Live
/c/Windows/System32/Wbem
/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0
/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Live/Shared
/c/Users/Tomy/.dnx/bin
/c/Program Files/Microsoft DNX/Dnvm
/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/130/Tools/Binn
/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/110/DTS/Binn
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/120/DTS/Binn
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/130/DTS/Binn
/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/120/Tools/Binn
/c/Program Files/dotnet
/c/php
/c/curl
/c/Users/Tomy/Pear
/c/Program Files/PuTTY
/c/Program Files (x86)/Bitvise SSH Client
/c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin
/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin
/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/bin
/c/glassfish/glassfish/bin
/c/Program Files (x86)/Brackets/command
/c/Program Files (x86)/GtkSharp/2.12/bin
/c/Program Files/Microsoft/Web Platform Installer
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/140/DTS/Binn
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Azure/CLI/wbin
/c/Users/Tomy/AppData/Roaming/npm
/cmd
/c/Users/Tomy/AppData/Roaming/npm
/c/Program Files/nodejs
/c/php
/c/Users/Tomy/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/bin
/usr/bin/vendor_perl
/usr/bin/core_perl
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/mingw64/lib/pkgconfig
/mingw64/share/pkgconfig
INFOPATH=/usr/local/info
/usr/share/info
/usr/info
/share/info
HOMEPATH=\Users\Tomy
ORIGINAL_PATH=/mingw64/bin
/usr/bin
/c/Users/Tomy/bin
/c/Ruby24-x64/bin
/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath
/c/Program Files/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/Windows Live
/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/Windows Live
/c/Windows/system32
/c/Windows
/c/Windows/System32/Wbem
/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0
/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Live/Shared
/c/Users/Tomy/.dnx/bin
/c/Program Files/Microsoft DNX/Dnvm
/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/130/Tools/Binn
/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/110/DTS/Binn
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/120/DTS/Binn
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/130/DTS/Binn
/c/ProgramData/Anaconda3
/c/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Scripts
/c/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Library/bin
/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/120/Tools/Binn
/c/Program Files/dotnet
/c/Program Files (x86)/Skype/Phone
/c/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Utilities 1.6
/c/php
/c/curl
/c/Users/Tomy/Pear
/c/Program Files/PuTTY
/c/Program Files (x86)/Bitvise SSH Client
/c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin
/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin
/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/bin
/c/glassfish/glassfish/bin
/c/Program Files (x86)/Brackets/command
/c/Program Files (x86)/GtkSharp/2.12/bin
/c/Program Files/Microsoft/Web Platform Installer
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/140/DTS/Binn
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Azure/CLI/wbin
/c/Users/Tomy/AppData/Roaming/npm
/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Windows Performance Toolkit
/cmd
/c/Users/Tomy/AppData/Roaming/npm
/c/Program Files/nodejs
/c/php
/c/Users/Tomy/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/bin
```

and the second log:

```html
Desktop(master) > cat ~/.bash_profile
export PS1='\W$(__git_ps1 "(%s)")
```

Comment: Could you run the following two commands and share their output please (hide if there's anything sensitive there)? `printenv | grep PATH= | tr ':' '\n'` -- to list what's in your PATH. `cat ~/.bash_profile` to see what PATH extension(s) may be added for Git Bash specifically.

Comment: done those two commands.

Comment: Your `PATH` looks good to me. Actually, I start believing it's not really a Git Bash issue at all. I assume a few things: a) if you run `which node` and `which npm` _directly from Git Bash_ it shows their right locations; b) you installed the `sails` things as a global package (i.e. `npm install -g sails`), and `which sails` also points to the right place... If "a" is true, I'm very positive your issue is unrelated to Git Bash... If "b" is true, I don't even know where to start debugging this, my friend.

Comment: It's also possible, yet unlikely that there's a bug _within `sails`_ that makes is search for the executables in wrong places.

Comment: reinstalled git+node, cleaned all folders, except for roaming..node_modules and seems it is working now.

Comment: Great to hear that

Comment: I figured out what was the problem --- it was adding manually to system variable path "User/Appdata/Roaming/npm" right before node.js . Should not add it manually, as is advised in many 'how-to node' videos.